# How Can I Set the Post Author of a Post I Just Created With PHP?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, author, wp-insert-post, wp-update-post

I'm using PHP to dynamically create a custom post, and I need the author to be someone other than the logged in user. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759359/wordpress-manually-set-the-author-of-a-post-in-php but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it after the post is already inserted. I guess I could just do a db query...

Comment: I'm not really grasping what you are doing, but is there a way to pass the post ID nto wp_update_post? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the ID of the author you can use wp_insert_post specifying the ID and the author ID to it.

```
$id = $post->ID; // change this to whathever
$user_id = '4'; // change this too

$the_post = array();
$the_post['ID'] = $id;
$the_post['post_author'] = $user_id;

wp_insert_post( $the_post );
```

The trick is to specify the ID to update the post. See [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Comment: i was looking at wp_insert_post and thought that the user_id was hard coded. but it was just set as the default. and maybe it was another bug that caused it not to work. duh! thanks.

Comment: and why are you using useraidi and not user_id. odd.

Comment: Because you needed *something else* than the actual logged author. Besides, I'm not a fan of using too default name variables, never knows.

Comment: But what about `arrayh();`? This won't ever work... Plus: Using localized names makes it hard for others to understand your code. This is imo more important if you're answering on a public Q/A site that should be a reference for thousands of people.

Comment: @kaiser fixed the array thing.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity and relevancy between this question and another question asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) ([wordpress - manually set the author of a post in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759359/wordpress-manually-set-the-author-of-a-post-in-php) -- As linked by OP here on WPSE.).

WordPress seems to force a value for the `post_author` while inserting or updating posts using [`wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

**The way around it is to use the filter hook `wp_insert_post_data`.**

```
/**
 * Filter slashed post data just before it is inserted into the database.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param array $data    An array of slashed post data.
 * @param array $postarr An array of sanitized, but otherwise unmodified post data.
 */
$data = apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_data', $data, $postarr );
```

**Example Usage of filter hook `wp_insert_post_data`:**

```
function remove_author_id( $data, $postarr ) {

    if ( $data['post_type'] != 'YOUR-POST-TYPE-HERE' ) {
        return $data;
    }

    $data['post_author'] = 0;

    return $data;

}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'remove_author_id', '99', 2 );
```

This can be particularly nice for inserting or updating posts using `PHP`.

**Note:** You will want to be sure to disable the support for `author` in your Custom Post Type and probably be cautious using any author related functions within the scope of this Post Type.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a custom post type and you don't want an author assigned to a post you can remove 'author' from `supports( array )` in register_post_type.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

If you still need author support for your post type, this would make much more sense to just do this in post.php / post-new.php by filtering the author metabox.

The solution is to add a none or null user to the dropdown using wp_dropdown_users `'show_option_none'`  WordPress will use `<option value="-1">` for your null user but it will show up as 0 in the db.

*Note:  This example also moves the author div right above the publish button.

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'move_author_meta' );

function move_author_meta() {
    global $post_ID;
    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    echo '<div id="author" class="misc-pub-section" style="border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:1px; border-top-color:#EEEEEE; border-bottom-width:0px;">Author: ';
    better_author_meta_box( $post );  //This function is being called in replace author_meta_box()

    echo '</div>';

}

function better_author_meta_box($post) { ?>

   <label class="screen-reader-text" for="post_author_override"><?php _e('Author'); ?></label>
  <?php

    if ( 'auto-draft' == $post->post_status ) : $selected = false; elseif (  $post->post_author == 0 || ( ! $post->post_author) ) : $selected = -1; else : $selected = $post->post_author; endif;
    wp_dropdown_users( array(
            'who' => 'authors',
            'name' => 'post_author_override',
            'selected' => $selected ? $selected : (int) -1,
            'include_selected' => true,
            'show_option_none' => 'NONE',
            'orderby'          => 'display_name',
            'show'             => 'display_name',
            'order'            => 'ASC'
      ) );
  }
```

Im sure you notice all the extra conditional checks for $selected.  It might be overkill but eliminated any issues with editors not being able to change an author to none from previous published posts.